# Clementine remote

Tags: remote-access, clementine

I am running Clementine 1.3.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I downloaded the remote app on my android. I did open port 5500 but I cannot get it to connect. I can ping the phone and the phone can ping the computer.  The computer is connected via Ethernet. Clementine remote works on my laptop but if I change the host address on the phone to my PC it cannot connect.  I don't think it is a problem with the phone or the router unless there is something in LAN settings I am missing. What info can I post for help?

on PC

```
$ nmap -p 5500 10.0.0.3 5500
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-07-07 12:09 EDT
Strange read error from 0.0.21.124 (22 - 'Invalid argument')
Strange read error from 0.0.21.124 (22 - 'Invalid argument')
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.3
Host is up (0.00011s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5500/tcp open  hotline
```

Laptop that works:

```
5500/tcp open hotline
```

Comment: What is your Clementine version? From Play Store --> Clementine Remote app: `IMPORTANT:
You need at least Clementine 1.3 to use this remote!`

Comment: 1.3.1 freshly installed. On the laptop I added the repository, on the PC I used .deb file. should I try using the repo on my PC?

Comment: I assume you activated the remote control in the settings ... can you provide the output of `nmap -p 5500 <ip-address>` from the host and maybe a second system? Please update the question with these additional information.

Comment: Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.04 seconds

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information. Comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning.

Comment: Have you tried using another port?